# MessageBox.Show not working at all

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, messagebox

I am developing an app for Windows Phone 8 with C#

And I've been working alot with `MessageBox.Show()` , and All the time it used to show a PopUp message like i wanted , but then suddenly , it Won't show anything , I debugged the app , the code runs normally and compiles the Line `MessageBox.Show("Something");`
but it doesn't pop up !

I also tried to put it in another page , doesn't work too !
All i remember that yesterday I have messed with **References of the Project**
But is that the problem ?

Anyways here's a photo of the references of my Project

[image: References]

Comment: you need `System.Windows Namespace`

Comment: Normally, if you are missing a reference, it won't even compile at all. Since it compiles, `MessageBox` may have unwittingly been pointing to something else. Try right-clicking on `MessageBox` and click on *Go to Definition* and see if it brings you to `System.Windows.MessageBox` class or somewhere else.

Comment: @SFLee it takes me to the `MessageBox` class

Comment: What I mean is: Does that `MessageBox` belong to .NET Framework's `System.Windows` or some other namespaces/assemblies?

Answer (score 4):

When you build a *Windows Phone Project* it automatically generates all the required dependencies for you.  You should be able to in your *class file* and add the following `using` statement:

```
using System.Windows
```

Once you've done that you'll be able to implement the `MessageBox` class.  If not, then you'll need to do the following:

1. Open *Solution Explorer*
2. Right Click *Reference Folder*
3. *Add* Reference
4. Go to *Assemblies*
5. Go to *Browse*
6. Navigate to: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework`
7. Reference `PresentationFramework.dll`

Once you've referenced that library, you'll be able to call: `MessageBox.Show(@"Something");` without a single hiccup.

Comment: Where i can add assemblies?

Comment: Followed till step 4 , and there's was nothing to choose there 

Only a message was showen :All of framework assemblies are already referenced . Please use the object browser to explore the references in the Framework

Comment: went to the Objcet Browser , found `System.Windows` and also found `MessageBox` class

Comment: but again , The windows in your picture doesn't show any assembly in my computer

Comment: 2012 Express for Windows Phone

Comment: I told you , its Targeting : Windows Phone 8.0

Comment: you cannot add framework assemblies for the windows phone 8 apps. all the framework assemblies are already referenced in windows phone 8 solutions implicitly.

Comment: @DreamCoder Fixed the answer to better define "steps".

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

1.) Restarted my computer

2.) Deleted the app from the phone

3.) Debug

Comment: Along these lines, I ended up just rebooting my phone and it started working again. Apparently, this is a Windows Phone 8.1 bug and not actually a problem with apps that run into this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with `MessageBox.Show()` not working.

It happened on two different pieces of software: Kaxaml, and an example from the Troelsen C# book.

I troubleshot it by just using a simple string inside the `Show()` instead of the "Exception" delegate in different spots in the code, and that helped tell me that I had the right references.  Obviously, if `MessageBox` worked in any place in the code at all, that told me I had the correct references.

Basically, what was happening was the Visual Studio debugger would fire before the catch-try blocks, preventing the MessageBox from ever appearing.  When I used the Release version, there would be no MessageBox either though.

What solved it was by just turning off a little click-box that said on Visual Studio, something like, "Don't show this exception".  Kind of odd that Visual Studio still fired off an exception error, even though it was in a catch-try block, but whatever, this worked for me.